# How to convert PHP code to C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I am trying to consume one service , and found the php code to access that service.

```
try {
 $client = new SoapClient(
 WSDL_URL,
 array(
 'trace' => true,
 'exceptions' => true
 )
 );
$return = $client->sendMessage(
 A,
 B,
 LandLine,
 'This is a test message.',
 Reference,
 NULL, //
 C,
 M
);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
//log error here
}
?>
```

I am trying to consume the same service from C# code,but before that i am trying to understand what the above code does? I am not getting what is $client-> means here and seems SoapClient() is also a method. could any body in php developers can tell me what above code is doing.

If i am writing the code in C# how method signature would be.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `new SoapClient(...)` is creating a new instance of the class. The variables inside will be used in the class's constructor method. `$client->sendMessage(...)` is calling that method on the class. Best to refer to the documentation to see what information these methods are expecting. I don't think it's using the built-in one, but here's the link anyway http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Create a new service reference and provide the WSDL URL. VS will create a WCF proxy class for you.